# Azure Application Proxy Does Not Accept Authorization Header

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

I have been trying to configure access to an on-premise Web API from a native application using this walkthrough: [How to enable native client applications to interact with proxy applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-native-client-application)

According to the walkthrough,

> "*To support native client applications, Application Proxy accepts Azure AD-issued tokens that are sent in the header.*"

However, regardless of the tokens that I send in the request header, the proxy always responds with HTTP 302 and redirects me to the sign in page.

Has anyone been able to pass Azure app proxy pre-authentication using a token?

Comment: Hello @Maxim, this is already a requested feature. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/36500158-enable-x-forwarded-host-in-response   https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19335826-cors-for-app-proxy

Comment: Thank you @Nishant. I am currently trying to work around this limitation by deploying a web app proxy on premise instead of an Azure app proxy and disabling pre-authentication. In the web app proxy, I am planning to use client certificate pre-authentication instead of AD, so it should resolve the issue. But I see that there are other workaround ideas in the forum posts that you have shared. If my workaround doesn't work, I will explore those. Thanks again.